# Swift array append not working on collectionView reload data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Inside of my collectionView cell i have a nested collection view. It is first updated after making an api call (didSet), but in a load more mechanism when i try to append data to the data source array and reload the collectionView..the changes are not reflected. Here is my code

```
class PhotosCollectionViewController:    

   UICollectionViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,
   UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


let network = networkingService()
let keychain = KeychainSwift()

var userID: String?
var code: String?

 var platesID: String!{
    
    didSet{
        
         let parameters: Parameters = [:]
        
        network.makeGetRequestDecodable(parameters: parameters, url: 
         "endpoint") { (reponse) in
            
            
            do {
                
                
                let modeled = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from:reponse)
                
                self.gps_singleton_posts = modeled
                print("Reload Method Called")
                self.appsCollectionView?.reloadData()
                
                
            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
 var gps_singleton_posts: [gps_sing]?
let gridId = "gridID"
var appsCollectionView: UICollectionView? = {
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 3

    
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return collectionView
    
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    
    
    
    
    if let value = keychain.get("userID") {
        self.userID = value
        // print("keychain\(self.userID!)")
    }
    if let value = keychain.get("security_token") {
        self.code = value
        // print("keychain\(self.code!)")
    }
    
   
    appsCollectionView?.dataSource = self
    appsCollectionView?.delegate = self
    appsCollectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 0, 0, 0)
     appsCollectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 
     0, 0, 0)
    
    addSubview(appsCollectionView!);
    
    
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: appsCollectionView!)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: appsCollectionView!)
    appsCollectionView?.register(ImageCell.self, 
    forCellWithReuseIdentifier: gridId)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   
    return CGSize(width: 123, height: 123)
   
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   
    print(gps_singleton_posts)
    if let count = gps_singleton_posts?.count{
        
        return count
    }

    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
   
let parameters: Parameters = [:]
    
    
  network.makeGetRequestDecodable(parameters: parameters, url: "Endpoiint") { (reponse) in
        
        
        do {
            
            
            let modeled = try JSONDecoder().decode([gps_sing].self, from:reponse)
            
            for model in modeled{
                self.gps_singleton_posts?.append(model)
            }
           print("Reload Method Called")
            collectionView.reloadData()
            print(self.gps_singleton_posts)
            
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
         }
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    print(self.gps_singleton_posts?.count)
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: gridId, for: indexPath)
        as! ImageCell
    
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cell.singlePost = gps_singleton_posts![indexPath.row]
    
    return cell
 
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
   
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}


 }


 class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {


var imageViewGrid: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0 , width: 100, height: 100)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "delete")
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

var textLabel: UILabel = {
    
    let lv = UILabel()
    lv.textColor = UIColor.red
    lv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return lv
}()

var singlePost: gps_sing! {
    
    didSet{
        
        let imageUrl = singlePost.uid
        print(imageUrl!)
        
        imageViewGrid.setImageWith(NSURL(string: imageUrl!)! as URL)
        
        
    }
    
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpViews()
}

func setUpViews(){
    
    addSubview(imageViewGrid)
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": imageViewGrid]))
    
    
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": imageViewGrid]))
    
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
} 
  }
```

In the above code (didSelectAt) function is used to load more items..but the changes are not reflected. Pleas help me out. Thanks a lot for answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i found the solution to my problem. In the above collection view i had disabled scrolling..because of which the added content after reload data was not showing up. Once i enabled scrolling the data started to show up.

Answer (score 1):

first of all: NEVER do layout changes in a parallel thread.

I'm seeing that in **platesID**'s `didSet` you are doing an API call and in its response you're trying to reload a collectionview. This kind of operations must be done in the main thread! Try to wrap the collectionview.reloadData() in this way

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.appsCollectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

I don't know if this will solve all your problems but the reloadData() action may not work properly in a secondary thread.

**Layout operations must always be launched on the main thread**.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Will try it out and get back to you

Comment: Just tried it...did not work :( Anything else i could do ?